# Why does using Fsutil make your windows computer run faster?

Tags: windows, fsutil

I have stumbled across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1Iyx2cCXJU) which supposedly makes your computer run faster:

```
Fsutil behaviour set memoryusage 2
```

However, I don't understand why it makes your computer faster. This seems too good to be true, can something really speed up your computer? Does it have any drawbacks or causes any hidden problems for your computer?

Comment: Search for “fsutil memoryusage 2”. The first link is to a Microsoft page explaining.. and no shortage of additional results.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior)?

Comment: Yes. It includes: “Setting memoryusage to 2 raises the limit of paged pool memory. This _might_ improve performance _if_ your system is opening and closing many files in the same file set _and_ is not already using large amounts of system memory for other apps or for cache memory.”

Comment: `Does it have any drawbacks or causes any hidden problems for your computer?` Yes - it uses more RAM.

Comment: okay, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely dependent on how you usually use your computer, and its specifications. From [Windows docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior):

> Configures the internal cache levels of NTFS paged-pool memory and
>   NTFS nonpaged-pool memory. Set to 1 or 2. When set to 1 (the default),
>   NTFS uses the default amount of paged-pool memory. When set to 2, NTFS
>   increases the size of its lookaside lists and memory thresholds. (A
>   lookaside list is a pool of fixed-size memory buffers that the kernel
>   and device drivers create as private memory caches for file system
>   operations, such as reading a file.)

so basically it increases the amount of paging your file system can use out of the total shared pool. This of course, means less for other processes. The documentation is even explicit about it:

> Increasing the physical memory doesn't always increase the amount of
>   paged pool memory available to NTFS. Setting memoryusage to 2 raises
>   the limit of paged pool memory. This might improve performance if your
>   system is opening and closing many files in the same file set and is
>   not already using large amounts of system memory for other apps or for
>   cache memory. If your computer is already using large amounts of
>   system memory for other apps or for cache memory, increasing the limit
>   of NTFS paged and non-paged pool memory reduces the available pool
>   memory for other processes. This might reduce overall system
>   performance. This parameter updates the
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsMemoryUsage
>   registry key.

So basically if your ram usage is not to high, it might be worth it, especially when loading and re-loading resources from your hard-drive. Gaming is a notable area of benefit, where often the GPU is doing most of the work, leaving the RAM somewhat free, and the same stuff needs to be loaded constantly. Of course, there is also a GPU cache for that, so the benefit increase is not straightforward.

Bottom line - this gives the file system more page space out of a total shared pool of fixed size, so is not "free".

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I understand it now.